# Using Viewport to scale image to width in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, viewport

I'm having problems persuading my remote images to scale to the correct size using UIWebView. This is probably a total n00b question, but am I doing it wrong/is there a better way?

I've looked at Viewport examples on StackOverflow and the code below seems to be correct, but large images are still stretching further than the screen width. I'd like all images to be displayed with the same width (to fill the screen) and the user to then be able to zoom in.

```
    NSString *urlAddress = image;


//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//set up html
NSString *htmlString = @"<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=320,user-scalable=yes,initial-scale=1.0\"></head><body><img style='width=100%' src='%@'></body></html>";
NSString *imageHTML  = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:htmlString, url];

// Load image in UIWebView
webImageView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[webImageView loadHTMLString:imageHTML baseURL:nil];
```

The 'image' variable is the location of the image on the server. Can anyone assist?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using a `UIWebView` to show an image, instead of just a regular old `UIImageView`?

Comment: Well I'm a total newbie and I read somewhere that to load images from a url it was easier just to display them in a UIWebView. Disagree?

Comment: I would advice against using a `UIWebView` if all you want to do is show an image -- using a `UIWebView` is overkill. What you should do is use `NSURLConnection` to load the image data, get the `UIImage`, and then show it in an `UIImageView`: the view that is meant for showing images, unlike `UIWebView` which is meant for showing HTML pages.

Comment: OK thanks Douwe, I'll play around and give that a go I guess...